# How to do Creation Updation and Deletion of Data from IList for Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-ajax, kendo-grid

this is my kendogrid code :

```html
KendoDemosFactory.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $sessionStorage) {
        $scope.mainGridOptions = {
            dataSource: {                
                transport: {
                    read: {url:"/User/GetUserDetail",datatype:"json"},
                    update: { url: "/User/UpdateUser", type: "POST" },
                    destroy:{ url:"/User/DeleteUser",type:"POST"},
                    Create:{url:"/User/CreateUser",type:"POST"}
                },
                parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                    }
                },
                
                batch: true,
                pageSize: 5,
                serverPaging: false,
                serverSorting: false
            },
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            navigatable: true,
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            dataBound: function () {
                this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
            },
            columns: [{
                field: "FirstName",
                title: "First Name",
                width: "80px"
            }, {
                field: "LastName",
                title: "Last Name",
                width: "80px"
            }, {
                field: "Address",
                width: "80px"
            }, {
                field: "Email",
                width: "100px"
            }, {
                field: "Gender",
                width: "80px"
            },
            {
                field: "Salary",
                width:"100px"
            },
            { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 100 }
            ],
            editable:true
        };
    })
```

and here is my controller with my userlist and all the methods :

```html
  public ActionResult GetUserDetail()
        {
            IList<UserModel> userList = new List<UserModel>()
            {
            new UserModel{
                id=1,
                FirstName = "Pawan",
                LastName = "Kapoor",
                Address = "Mohali",
                Email = "test@test.com",
                Gender = "Male",
                Salary = 25000
            },           

          new UserModel
            {
                id=2,
                FirstName = "Ayan",
                LastName = "Banerjee",
                Address = "Bangalore",
                Email = "test1@test.com",
                Gender = "Male",
                Salary = 30000
            },
}
}


[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateUser()
        {            
            IList<UserModel> userList = new List<UserModel>();
            return Json(userList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                        
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateUser()
        {
            IList<UserModel> userList = new List<UserModel>();
            return Json(userList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteUser()    
        {
            IList<UserModel> userList = new List<UserModel>();
            return Json(userList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My kendo Grid is populating fine with editable functionality and all the CRUD controls but i am not able to bind data with the controller using CRUD Methods(they are not getting hit and any crud functionality is not getting persisted). Please help

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a few notes to correct your your code.

- If you do not want to make batch update, send to controller only the current row.

  ```
  parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
      if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
           return { models: options.models[0] };
      }
  }
  ```
- Correct your update action method as follows: MVC will bind the data send from grid into UserModel.

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult UpdateUser(UserModel model)
  {
      // do something with model 
      return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  ```

[This link will lead you to solve your problem](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net-mvc/tree/master/grid-crud/Controllers)

Comment: Thanks for your input,but i am a little weak on MVC side, so finding it a bit difficult to write my code in CreateUser and UpdateUser Methods. my current concern is : while creating or updating a new user ,how do i send that data (with id,firstname and all other fields) to my action and have it persisted.can you help regarding that?